# IDisposable Question

Tags: c#

Say I have the following:

```
public abstract class ControlLimitBase : IDisposable 
{
}

public abstract class UpperAlarmLimit : ControlLimitBase 
{
}

public class CdsUpperAlarmLimit : UpperAlarmLimit 
{
}
```

Two Questions:

1.
I'm a little confused on when my IDisposable members would actually get called. Would they get called when an instance of CdsUpperAlarmLimit goes out of scope?

2.
How would I handle disposing of objects created in the CdsUpperAlarmLimit class? Should this also derive from IDisposable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Dispose()` is never called automatically - it depends on how the code is actually used.

1.) `Dispose()` is called when you specifically call `Dispose()`:

```
myAlarm.Dispose();
```

2.) `Dispose()` is called at the end of a `using` block using an instance of your type.

```
using(var myAlarm = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit())
{

}
```

The `using` block is syntactic sugar for a `try/finally` block with a call to `Dispose()` on the object "being used" in the finally block.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here. I've written a class that implements `IDisposable`, and when I use it in a `using` block the `Dispose()` method is never called. Does that mean I still need to call `Dispose()` inside my `using` block?

Comment: @jpcode: no you don't have to - the `using` block is equivalen to a `try/finally` with a `Dispose` call in the `finally` code block

Answer (score 5):

1. No, `IDisposable` won't be called just automatically. You'd *normally* call `Dispose` with a `using` statement, like this:

   ```
   using (ControlLimitBase limit = new UpperAlarmLimit())
   {
       // Code using the limit
   }
   ```

   This is effectively a try/finally block, so `Dispose` will be called *however* you leave the block.
2. `CdsUpperAlarmLimit` already implements `IDisposable` indirectly. If you follow the [normal pattern for implementing `IDisposable` in non-sealed classes](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae), you'll override `void Dispose(bool disposing)` and dispose your composed resources there.

Note that the garbage collector does *not* call `Dispose` itself - although it can call a *finalizer*. You should rarely use a finalizer unless you have a *direct* handle on unmanaged resources though.

To be honest, I usually find it's worth trying to change the design to avoid needing to keep hold of unmanaged resources in classes - implementing `IDisposable` properly in the general case is frankly a pain. It's not so bad if your class is sealed (no need for the extra method; just implement the `Dispose()` method) - but it still means your clients need to be aware of it, so that they can use an appropriate `using` statement.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm a little confused on when my IDisposable members would actually get called. Would they get called when an instance of CdsUpperAlarmLimit goes out of scope?

No. Its get called when you use `using` construct as:

```
using(var inst = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit())
{
    //...
}//<-------- here inst.Dispose() gets called.
```

But it doesn't get called if you write this:

```
{
   var inst = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit();
   //...
}//<-------- here inst.Dispose() does NOT get called.
```

However, you can write this as well:

```
var inst = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit();
using( inst )
{
    //...
}//<-------- here inst.Dispose() gets called.
```

Answer (score 3):

`IDisposable` has one member, `Dispose()`.

This is called when you choose to call it. Most typically that's done for you by the framework with the `using` block syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice recommend when you implement `Dispose()` method in non sealed class you should have a virtual method for your derived classes to override.

Read more on **Dispose pattern** here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

when using an IDisposable object, it's always good to use it this way:

```
using(var disposable = new DisposableObject())
{
    // do you stuff with disposable
}
```

After the using block has been run, the Dispose method will be called on the IDisposable object. Otherwise you would need to call Dispose manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. When someone calls `.Dispose` on it.
2. No, it already implements it through inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

IDisposable is implemented when you want to indicate that your resource has dependencies that must be explicitly unloaded and cleaned up. As such, IDisposable is never called automatically (like with Garbage Collection).

Generally, to handle IDisposables, you should wrap their usage in a using block

```
using(var x = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit()) { ... }
```

this compiles to:

```
CdsUpperAlarmLimit x = null;
try
{
   x = new CdsUpperAlarmLimit();
   ...
}
finally
{
   x.Dispose();
}
```

So, back to topic, if your type, CdsUpperAlarmLimit, is implementing IDisposable, it's saying to the world: "I have stuff that must be disposed". Common reasons for this would be:

- CdsUpperAlarmLimit keeps some OTHER IDisposable resources (like FileStreams, ObjectContexts, Timers, etc.) and when CdsUpperAlarmLimit is done being used, it needs to make sure the FileStreams, ObjectContexts, Timers, etc. also get Dispose called.
- CdsUpperAlarmLimit is using unmanaged resources or memory and must clean up when it's done or there will be a memory leak